# Keys are not repeating with Yosemite after 10.10.2

Tags: keyboard, macos

I never had a single issue with yosemite, until yestersday after updating to 10.10.2.

Now I press a key and hold it and it is not repeating anymore.

but the problem is selective. Spaces repeat. Symbols, punctuation mark repeats but numbers and letters don't.

Any way to make that work again?

Nope, that is set (look pic). [image]

Comment: no, this is the regular keyboard (imac). Found the solution. See my answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: so when you pressed and hold a key there was a pop up showing the accent options for it! but it did not do the repeat ?

Comment: Please don't delete questions just because they are linked as duplicates. Mod message me or flag this if you're not clear about deletion / self destruction guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer: type this on terminal

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```